# Periodically Update a TextView in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am using the MediaPlayer class to play an mp3 file in my application. How do I update a textview control every second with the current position in the mp3 file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html) on the Android developer's blog should answer your question.